# How can I build a list from a JSON array based on a selected value?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create a filtered select list of sources based on the media selected. I know the method I used below filters but does not display the list correctly. I am half asleep and trying to correct this and need some input from someone. :-) Cheers!

```
let types = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "media": "TV",
    "source": "wkbw"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "media": "TV",
    "source": "wffo"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "media": "TV",
    "source": "wtrw"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "media": "Radio",
    "source": "wrqa"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "media": "Radio",
    "source": "wuqa"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "media": "Radio",
    "source": "wzzt"
  }
]

$("#type").change(function() {
    $("#results").empty();
    selected = $("#type").val();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
    // some kind of filter source by selected the one below isn't quite right
    // $("#results").append("<option value='" + types[i].source + "'>" + types[i].source + "</option>");
    source = types.filter(types => types.media === selected).map(d => d.source).join('');
    $("#results").append("<option value='" + source + "'>" + source + "</option>");
  }
});
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/simplymarkb/sk0rdf2j/31/

Comment: You are using loop also and filter also , why so?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Actually I just need to display the results in another select. Won't I need to use a loop to build it? This is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The point is filter will internally loop over all the elements

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi I figured that but the issue is how can I use my filter to build the select list?

Comment: See the working solution below.

Comment: Once you have filtered out the data , just loop over that array and build the list

Comment: Something like this you can do :   source = types.filter(types => types.media === selected).map(d => d.source);
    console.log(source[0])
  for(let i=0;i<source.length;i++){
    $("#results").append("<option value='" + source[i] + "'>" + source[i] + "</option>");
  }
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `filter` outside the loop and get the value of `source[i]` in the option.

Also just use `.html()` to empty the `select` again `onchange`.

Here you go => Working Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/u38hrox1/11/

Just run snippet to see it action.

```js
let types = [
  {
"id": 1,
"media": "TV",
"source": "wkbw"
  },
  {
"id": 2,
"media": "TV",
"source": "wffo"
  },
  {
"id": 3,
"media": "TV",
"source": "wtrw"
  },
  {
"id": 8,
"media": "Radio",
"source": "wrqa"
  },
  {
"id": 9,
"media": "Radio",
"source": "wuqa"
  },
  {
"id": 10,
"media": "Radio",
"source": "wzzt"
  }
]

$("#type").change(function() {
  $("#results").html('')
  var selected = $("#type").val();
  var source = types.filter(types => types.media === selected).map(d => d.source);
  for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    $("#results").append("<option value='" + source[i] + "'>" + source[i] + "</option>");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type">
  <option value="TV">TV</option>
  <option value="Radio">Radio</option>
</select>
<hr>
<select id="results">..results</select>
```

Comment: The use of filter and map here is really unnecessarily complicated. It all could be replaced with simple if statement as in my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. BUT the OP wants to have filter there and built it that way as there is no HARM at using filter depending on your JSON data. Its ideal to have a look at the comments. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite your code with a simple if statement like this:

```
   let types = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "media": "TV",
    "source": "wkbw"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "media": "TV",
    "source": "wffo"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "media": "TV",
    "source": "wtrw"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "media": "Radio",
    "source": "wrqa"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "media": "Radio",
    "source": "wuqa"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "media": "Radio",
    "source": "wzzt"
  }
]

$("#type").change(function() {
    $("#results").empty();
    selected = $("#type").val();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
    if(types[i].media === selected){
      $("#results").append("<option value='" + types[i].source + 
          "'>" + types[i].source + "</option>");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following solution

```js
let types = [
  {
    id: 1,
    media: "TV",
    source: "wkbw",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    media: "TV",
    source: "wffo",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    media: "TV",
    source: "wtrw",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    media: "Radio",
    source: "wrqa",
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    media: "Radio",
    source: "wuqa",
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    media: "Radio",
    source: "wzzt",
  },
];

const type = document.querySelector("#type");
const result = document.querySelector("#result");

type.addEventListener("change", changeHandler);

function changeHandler(event) {
  const output = types
    .filter((type) => type.media === event.target.value)
    .map((type) => `<option value="${type.source}">${type.source}</option>`)
    .join("");

  result.innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<select name="type" id="type">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select value</option>
  <option value="TV">TV</option>
  <option value="Radio">Radio</option>
</select>

<select name="result" id="result"></select>

<script src="app.js"></script>
```